# (Flutter) Infinite Scroll `ListView.builder` with Finite Content

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

## 1. The Problem

**How do I make my `ListView.builder` be able to scroll to empty space both to the top and to the bottom?**

For example, I have a list of custom widgets, and I would like the user to be able to get the top card on the list — which is at the top of the screen — closer to his thumb by scrolling to it, while `Flutter` renders the top space with an empty background.

## 2. What I've tried so far

The basic shape of my code is a basic implementation of the `ListView.builder` constructor:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: widgetsList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index){
    return widgetsList[index];
  },
),
```

I've tried fiddling with some of the [`ListView.builder`'s properties](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) and also some workarounds so far:

1. At first, I thought that either `shrinkWrap: true` or `physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()` — maybe I have to set the `parent` parameter of `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`? — would do the job, but none of them seem to work.
2. I've also tried to do this artifially by creating empty `Container`s both on the top and the bottom of the list, and adding something like `dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.values[1]` — I don't think that's how you use the `.values` property actually — to make the list start from the second value, but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe I should go for a `CustomScrollView` or use the `controller` property of the `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible to be achived with your "`Container` workaround". You could use a `ScrollController` and have its `initialScrollOffset` where the top `Container` ends. It is something I only later found out [through this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58885038/4756173).

1. Declare your `ScrollController` inside your widget's class.

   ```dart
   ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController(
     initialScrollOffset: 10, // or whatever offset you wish
     keepScrollOffset: true,
   );
   ```
2. Add the controller to your `ListView`

   ```dart
   ListView.builder(
     controller: scrollController,
     itemCount: widgetsList.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index){
       return widgetsList[index];
     },
   ),
   ```

Additionally, you may even want to create animations for the background scrolling action. That is possible through using the `.animateTo` method inside your widget's `initState`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, your best bet would be using a `CustomScrollView` with an expandable space in the `SliverAppBar`.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
         SliverAppBar(
           automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // gets rid of the back arrow
           expandedHeight: 250, // the collapsible space you want to use 
           flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
             background: Container(
               color: Colors.transparent
             ),
           ),
         ),
         SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) {
              // put your widgetsList here
            },
            childCount: widgetsList.length,
          ),
        ),
      ]
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: The behavior of the `SliverAppBar` is apparently what I want, where the box seems flexible to go up and down in height. But how to I render my list of widgets (cards) inside of the `FlexibleSpaceBar`?

Comment: Your list comes after the `FlexibleSpaceBar`, you use the `SliverList` inside of the `(context, index) {}`

Comment: But that would render my scrollable list below the box with flexible height you've just designed, which is not what I had in mind.

Comment: Do you have a preview of what do you want to achieve?

Comment: There isn't much to it, it's just having `Flutter` fill the top with empty space when trying to make the first item of the `ListView` get to the bottom of the screen. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/5TwTBSH) is something I did with `Adobe XD` that might be of help.

Comment: After messing around with it, this actually does seem to work, and I intend to maybe edit your code to have it closer to what I wanted originally. I just used one `SliverAppBar` at the top and another at the bottom. But two problems I'm having right now are: (1) how to disable the blurring effect of the top `SliverAppBar` when it's collapsing? (2) how do I start the page scroll from the cards and not the first `SliverAppBar`?

Comment: Another question I have, related to your answer, is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58884360/4756173).