# How to Disable the Blur Effect When Collapsing a `SliverAppBar` in a `CustomScrollView`

Tags: listview, flutter, customscrollview

## 1. The Context

I'm trying to make a `ListView` that has some empty space at the top so the user can bring top cards to the bottom of the screen, where she can easily access them with her thumb. As discussed in [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58839641/4756173), I couldn't make this happen with a regular `ListView`, so I switched to its parent, a `CustomScrollView`.

However, after adding a top `SliverAppBar`, when I get close to collapsing it, the space blurs into darker shades of grey, as seen in the image below. How can I disable this effect?

[image]

## 2. The Code

The `SliverAppBar I'm using so far is:

```dart
SliverAppBar(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // gets rid of the back arrow
  expandedHeight: 250, // the collapsible space you want to use 
  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
    background: Container(
      color: Colors.transparent
    ),
  ),
),
```

I've also tried to modify my `flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar`, but it didn't seem to work:

```dart
flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
  title: AnimatedOpacity(
    opacity: 0.0,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  ),
  collapseMode: CollapseMode.none,
  stretchModes: [
    StretchMode.fadeTitle,
  ],
  background: Container(color: Colors.grey[850]),
),
```

Comment: I can't see in your screenshot where the blurring is. Can you share a screenshot of how it looks before starting the collapse?

Comment: The blurring *can* be seen in the screenshot. It's the different shade of grey (different than the overall background) between the top black card and the top bar.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the elevation of SliverAppBar? e.g (SliverAppBar(elevation: 100.0),),

Answer (score 0):

It seems the default background color for the SliverList is the canvasColor of the theme. I've managed to make the colors match by using that theme color on your Container on the background of the FlexibleSpaceBar:

```
FlexibleSpaceBar(
  background: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
  ),
)
```