# How to make a `ListView.builder` Start at a Specific Index

Tags: listview, flutter

## 1. The Problem

Is there a way for a `ListView.builder` to start, say, at the second (`index = 1`) item of a list of widgets?

In my case — more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58839641/4756173) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58884360/4756173) if you're interested —, I'm trying to add some empty space at the top of a `ListView` so the user can scroll the top card closer to his thumb. A workaround would be to add empty `Container`s to the top and bottom of the `List` of widgets to simulate empty space. However, the `ListView` will render the `Container`s on the screen and user might become confused and not know that there are more cards available by simply scrolling.

Maybe there is a way of doing this with a `ScrollController`?

## 2. Some Template Code

I don't think that exposing code will help much because I'm just using a typical `ListView.builder`, but here it is in case you need a refresher.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: widgetsList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index){
    return widgetsList[index];
  },
),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `ScrollController` and have its `initialScrollOffset` where you want it to originally be.

1. Declare your `ScrollController` inside your widget's class.

   ```dart
   ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController(
     initialScrollOffset: 10, // or whatever offset you wish
     keepScrollOffset: true,
   );
   ```
2. Add the controller to your `ListView`

   ```dart
   ListView.builder(
     controller: scrollController,
     itemCount: widgetsList.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index){
       return widgetsList[index];
     },
   ),
   ```

Additionally, you may even want to create animations for the background scrolling action. That is possible through using the `.animateTo` method inside your widget's `initState`.

Comment: When you dont have the height of your child list items this fails

Answer (score 2):

`initialScrollOffset` can be confusing as the   initialScrollOffset's value is not the same as index.

This is the solution I have used overtime and it works perfectly well.
Use this Package as your ListView Builder
[scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list)

The package has a property called `initialScrollIndex`.
The value you supply will be the index where the listView will start from, irrespective of how large the data is, it works well.

Most importantly, the value of your `initialScrollIndex` must not be out of range,
so as a good developer, it's essential you check the length of the data  before assigning a value to the `initialScrollIndex`.

> StartIndex is the index you want your listView to start from

`initialScrollIndex: alldataLength > startIndex ? startIndex : 0`

This will safely set the initial index to 0 if the supplied startIndex is out of range.

This works perfectly well, You can try it out !